# Not sure how to call my function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I select my data I can do a simple join to resolve the values of some of the columns but not all.  Most of my columns have one value of data, like 10997, but other columns have multiple values of data, like 10997, 10889, 10123.  I have created a function to resolve the three separate values in to the text I need but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to use it.

I have a basic join like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The result of this will look like this:

```
Column1         Column2                     Column3
    1       11272, 11273, 11274, 11277          7712
```

The function I created uses declared variables and a table variable.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, dbo.MyFunction(COLUMN2), COLUMN3
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Resulting in this:

```
Column1         Column2                     Column3
    1       Radio, Flyer, Internet, Bar         7712
```

The problem is that my function uses variables and I can't find where to put it in SQL (table valued function, stored proc, etc) so I can use it how I'd like.  Each area has it's own limitation.

EDIT: Here is the code I created for my function, currently it's in a multi-statement table-valued function

```
DECLARE @looper INT, @res VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @outList VARCHAR(300) 

SET @outList = ''

DECLARE @tmpa TABLE (Item INT)

INSERT INTO @tmpa
SELECT Item
FROM fn_Split (', ', @input)

SELECT @looper = MIN(Item)
FROM @tmpa

WHILE @looper IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @res = NAME
        FROM FSM_CustomFormSelectOptions CFSO
        WHERE ID = @looper
        --print @res
        SET @outList = @outList + @res + ', '

        SELECT @looper = MIN(Item) FROM @tmpa WHERE Item > @looper
    END

    SET @outList = LEFT(@outList, LEN(@outList)-1)

    INSERT INTO @Answers
    VALUES(@outList)

    RETURN
```

Sample call is:

```
select * from fn_GetAnswerText( '11273, 11274, 11275')
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you how to use **your function** that **you wrote** if you don't provide the code for it so we can see what you're asking?

Comment: No the result from that basic join does not look like that.

Comment: Your function is wrong for what you're wanting it to produce as output. It needs to return a VARCHAR containing a comma-separated list of values, not a table, in order to be used as you want.

Comment: That makes sense but I still don't know what I need to do.  Does this mean I need to make this a stored proc?

Comment: He is creating a VARCHAR.  He is just not returning it.

Answer (score 0):

You  are not returning anything

RETURN  @outList

Comment: This produces an error:  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Facebook, Email, Flyer' to data type int.  That is because RETURN is an INT, not a string

Comment: Then change your function to return an string.